# Reference for the proof of Langlands conjecture for $GL_n$ over function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Is there any reference written in English for the proof of Langlands conjecture for $GL_n$ over function fields?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you mean by reference, but this might work

- Gérard Laumon, "[The Langlands Correspondence for Function Fields following  Laurent Lafforgue](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cdm/1999/1999/0001/CDM-1999-1999-0001-a004.pdf)" (1999)

It is a brief sketch of the everywhere unramified case with references to the original (french) papers. As far as I know there's no complete exposition of the proof in english.

There's some other (even shorter) expositions of the result and its context, for example

- Michael Rapoport, "[The work of Laurent Lafforgue](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/rapoport/preprints/lafforgue.pdf)" (2003)
- Gérard Laumon, "[The work of Laurent Lafforgue](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0212417)" (2002)